# Running Powershell from CMD Causing Command Line to Not Parse Correctly

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to run the following PowerShell code via a CMD shell:

```
$logfile = "x:\test.log"
try {
get-service
Add-Content - Path $logfile -Value "It Worked"
} catch {
Add-Content -Path $logfile -Value $_.Exception.Message
}
```

From a CMD script I am calling the script as follows:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "I paste the code above 
here"
```

I have also tried it as follows:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "& 'Command From Above'"
```

You can see from the error, it doesn't seem to be trying to run the entire command, because it seems to be trying to run my log command:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn96h.jpg

If I run something simple, it works without issue.  As follows:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "get-service"
```

Comment: It's an interesting question, but please always post the actual command you're executing, along with the error message you're getting, not (just) a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for **what you tried**:

- When calling from `cmd.exe`, PowerShell **code** you pass to Windows PowerShell's CLI, `powershell.exe` (`pwsh.exe` for PowerShell *Core*) **must be *single-line***:

  - Your screenshot suggests that you indeed used a single line, but **you're missing `;` chars. between your statements**; these *statement separators* are needed whenever you want to place multiple statements on a single line.
- Your next problem is related to passing the code as *individual* arguments to `-command`, to be pieced together by PowerShell before execution (as opposed to trying to pass a single argument with outer double-quoting).

  - **In passing arguments *individually*, any enclosing `"..."` are *stripped*** on parsing by PowerShell, so that `"x:\test.log"` turns into `x:\test.log` - no quotes - which caused the error you saw.

---

A **solution**:

By:

- properly separating your statements with `;`
- escaping the `"` chars. in your command as `\"` (sic)

you can get your command to work:

```
powershell -c $logfile = \"x:\test.log\"; try { get-service; Add-Content -Path $logfile -Value \"It Worked\" } catch { Add-Content -Path $logfile -Value $_.Exception.Message }
```

Generally, however, note that if your code happens to contain characters (also) reserved in `cmd.exe` - notably `& | < > % ^` - you would have to individually `^`-escape them.

It's challenging to get quoting right on the command line, and **ultimately the only robust solution** - short of avoiding the problem by creating a (temporary) *script file* - is to **use PowerShell's 
`-EncodedCommand` [CLI parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, which takes a Base64-encoded representation of the PowerShell code using the UTF-16LE character encoding.

Unfortunately, such a representation is not easy to come by in batch files.

Answer (score 0):

I have always had trouble calling multi-line PowerShell scripts through cmd.

I have seen people convert their script into base64 and run that string from PowerShell but I can't remember how.

The easiest way would be to save your script as a .PS1 and run `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\ps.ps1"`

Otherwise you could ECHO each line out to a .ps1 file and then run it. Would work as a .bat file.

```
@echo off
set WD=%~dp0
ECHO $logfile = "x:\test.log" >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
ECHO try { >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
ECHO     get-service; >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
ECHO     Add-Content - Path $logfile -Value "It Worked" >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
ECHO } catch { >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
ECHO     Add-Content -Path $logfile -Value $_.Exception.Message >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
ECHO } >> "%WD%Script.ps1"
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%WD%Script.ps1"
del "%WD%Script.ps1"
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your explanation and example.  Very useful!